# Query Posts that have or don't have a meta_value and order by the same ASC

Tags: query, meta-query, order

I'm trying to perform a scheduled update to all posts, 10 posts at time.

To achieve this, I run Cron job with a script that saves 2 post meta:

- `$DATA`: the data I want to be update
- `$TIME`: the UNIX timestamp: `time()`, to know when that post has been updated with a new `$DATA`

As I have a lot of posts that do not have the `$DATA` postmeta, when I query the posts to perform the update I want the posts to be ordered like this:

1. First I want any post that does **not** have the `$TIME` postmeta
2. Then all others, starting from the ones I've updated earlier

These are the query arguments I'm using:

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'posts_per_page' => '10',
   'meta_query' => array(
      'relation' => 'OR',
       array( 
               'key' => 'TIME_meta_key',
               'compare' => 'EXISTS'
           ),
         array(
               'key' => 'TIME_meta_key',
               'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
               'value' => 'xxx'  // I've read this is a bug, so I put a value even if it's ignored
           ),
       ),
   'orderby' => 'TIME_meta_key',
   'order' => 'ASC'
 );
```

As I said before, the `TIME_meta_key` value (when exists) is just a UNIX timestamp.

So, as I want to update first the posts that are still not updated, then the ones that have been updated earlier in time, I assume I have to order ASC.

But if I set ASC, this does not work. it keep updating the posts that already have a value in the `TIME_meta_key` field.

Is this normal or I'm making some stupid mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by naming index of meta query, then passing array of these names in `orderby` parameter

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'posts_per_page' => '10',
   'meta_query' => array(
      'relation' => 'OR',
      'with_time' => array( 
               'key' => 'TIME_meta_key',
               'compare' => 'EXISTS'
           ),
      'without_time' => array(
               'key' => 'TIME_meta_key',
               'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
               /* 'value' => 'xxx'  The bug has been fixed ; */
           ),
       ),
   /* First order posts those does not have meta key then those have meta key in ascending order */
   'orderby' => array(
       'without_time' => 'ASC',
       'with_time' => 'ASC'
   ),
 );
```

In orderby array first key is `without_time` then `with_time` thus it will bring up all the posts first those does not have `TIME_meta_key` however, these posts will not have order (Will be default based on ID) because meta key does not exist. Then it will join the posts those have meta key `TIME_meta_key` in ascending order.

So the final outcome will be `posts without meta key orderby ID` then `posts with meta key order by value ascending`.

> NOTE 1:  these syntax are only supported since WordPress version 4.2
>   
>   NOTE 2: Another bug related to `NOT EXIST` has been fixed in WordPress
>   3.9

Comment: thanks for answer Sumit. So I was trying to do something not possibile?

Comment: Yes it will not work because when you set order by time, first those posts comes up those have time!

Comment: I imagined that, indeed this is the doubt for I've posted this question. What would happen to posts with the TIME_meta_key empty? Would they be selected at the beginning or be skipped as well? And more generical: empty values can be sorted?

Comment: @bluantinoo I've updated my answer for your queries. And I will say please run this code then only you can see real output!

Comment: I will try your solution asap, and check your answer if it works (quite sure it does), don't worry!

Comment: Finally i got the chance to test it. it works! Thanks @Sumit, and sorry for the delay :)